# How to lock the composer extent in QGIS?

Tags: print-composer, qgis-2.12, lock

Is there a way to lock the print composer view extent map? This is my print composer:

[image]

If I change the scale bar in the canvas the composer change also. I try to use those options but with no success.

This is the canvas screen:

[image]

[image]

If i using "Sync composer with map" plugin [image] after i chnging the scale, then the composer scale change also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to fix a map on a specific scale in the map composer, then click on the `Data defined override -> Edit ->` (as you can see below) and enter the scale value that you want (only number), for example 100000.

[image]

The above procedure will fix the scale, but will not fix any addtional layer that you may put on the map view. If you want **freeze** the map composer to show only specific layers, then click/check `Lock layers for map item` located under the scale.

If you want freeze the extent, then copy each value of xmin, ymin, xmax, and ymax, and click `Data defined override -> Edit ->` and paste each value to its corresponding box. This will fix the extent completely.

[image]

Comment: when i using "Sync composer with map" plugin the scale changing in the composer, even i did your advice.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the composer window, select your map. Go to "item properties", then "Layers" and tock "Lock layers". Would that do the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is just to create a new print composer with your specified extents in the print composer manager. Any time you would like to change the map but keep the extent, simply copy the current print composer and than add, remove items, layers etc. Like this you do not have to copy your coordinates all the time.