# Defining and altering the extent of a map in print layout of QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

How can I change the extent of a map in print layout to be a custom-sized region. I would like to be able to drag the handles of of the bounding box to resize them so that they touch the purple box. Currently dragging the handles makes the map rescale to be smaller but the doesn't "crop" the box.

Alternatively, is it possible to use a map layer to define the extent of the map? The purple areas is a vector layer that I would like to use to "crop" the map area by.

[image: map with white space to be cropped out]

On QGis version 3.28.2-Firenze

Edit: I was able to get achieve something close to the behaviour I wanted by checking "Lock layers". Item Properties>Layers>Lock layers, and then dragging to the bounding box handles. See this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/219768/176125)

Comment: You need to set the map frame manually where you want the map to be in the layout and then switch to the 'Move Item Content' mode to interactively center/zoom the map extents as desired. Alternatively, use the Map Item Properties panel manually change the map Extent and Scale properties. To automate this, look at how to use the Atlas feature. In short, you will define the 'purple' layer as the Atlas Coverage Layer, and then set your Map item to be 'controlled by Atlas', with a 0% margin: this will tightly frame the map around the 'purple' layer object(s)

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/445296/88814

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Determine the map size and aspect rato of your purpule box. Use the same aspect ratio in Width and Height parameter.

[image: set size of a map]

2. Configure a map atlas with your purple layer as Coverage layer
3. Tick Item Properties -> Controlled by Atlas and set Margin around feature to 0 %.

[image]

Alternatively, you could also use your yellow layer and set margin at some percent - eg. 10 %. This way the aspect ratio of a map is not that important as you will have white space around feature anyway.